# Parsing Sub-Object from an XML Feed with objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, dynamic-arrays

I have an XML Feed to track a package

```
<xyz_name_of_company-objects version="1.0">
<object pk="1" model="awb">
<field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">5818537179673</field>
<field type="CharField" name="origin">AMSTERDAM</field>
<field type="CharField" name="destination">BERLIN</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_name">BRUSSELS</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_code">BRSL</field>
<field name="scans">
<object pk="1" model="scan_stages">
<field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">17 March, 2019, 03:10 </field>
<field type="CharField" name="status">In-Transit</field>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">002</field>
<field type="CharField" name="scan_status">PICKUP</field>
<field type="CharField" name="location_city">AMSTERDAM</field>
<field type="CharField" name="location_type">Hub</field>
<field type="CharField" name="city_name">AMSTERDAM</field>
<field type="CharField" name="Employee">JOEL - O94383</field>
</object>
<object pk="2" model="scan_stages">
<field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">18 March, 2019, 22:22 </field>
<field type="CharField" name="status">Bag scanned at Hub</field>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code"> - </field>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">003</field>
<field type="CharField" name="scan_status">IN</field>
<field type="CharField" name="location">I1H</field>
<field type="CharField" name="location_city">AMSTERDAM</field>
<field type="CharField" name="location_type">Hub</field>
<field type="CharField" name="city_name">AMSTERDAM</field>
<field type="CharField" name="Employee">ELLEN - 49821</field>
</object>
</field>
</object>
</xyz_name_of_company-objects>
```

As of now I had been using the following lines of code to get primary data like awb_number, origin, destination

```
$url = A Get URL with Credentials
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$awb = $xml->object->field[0];
$origin= $xml->object->field[1];
$destination = $xml->object->field[3];
```

Now my concern **was** to get data within

> **object pk="1" model="scan_stages"**

for the different scan stages which in my case I called the **scan statuses**.

[FYI : *These are different stages of a package in the network of the courier company*].

Finally I would like to build an array

```
    $SCANS = array(); // Master Array for all the Scans available
    foreach($xml->object->field[6] $scans)
    {
    $SCAN[] = array(); // Sub Array for each Scan
    foreach($scans as $scan_info)
    {
    $SCAN['scan'] = array($scan_info['name']=>$scan_info);
    }

    $SCANS[] = $SCAN;
    }
```

So, the output should be like

```
{
    "scan": {
        "employee": "JOEL - O94383",
        "location": "Amsterdam",
        "updated_on": "17 March, 2019, 03:10",
    }
    "scan": {
        "employee": "ELLEN - 49821",
        "location": "Amsterdam"
        "updated_on": "18 March, 2019, 22:22",
    }
}
```

My current output **array for each scan** looks like

```
[
    {
        "": {
            "@attributes": {
                "type": "CharField",
                "name": "Employee"
            },
            "0": "JOEL - O94383"
        }
    },
    {
        "": {
            "@attributes": {
                "type": "CharField",
                "name": "location_city"
            },
            "0": "AMSTERDAM"
        }
    },
    {
        "": {
            "@attributes": {
                "type": "DateTimeField",
                "name": "updated_on"
            },
            "0": "17 March, 2019, 03:10"
        }
    }
]
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is not a strict error, I think it is better to have an array of scan rather than several `scan` keys in the structure.

```
$object = $xml->xpath("//object[@pk = '1' and @model = 'awb']")[0] ;

// get all the scan stages object
$scanObjects = $object->xpath(".//object[@model = 'scan_stages']");

$scans = array(); // store all the scans info
foreach($scanObjects as $scanObject){
    $scan = array() ; // store the current scan info

    // iterate on all "field" in the current scan stage
    foreach($scanObject->xpath('field') as $field){
        $key = (string)$field->xpath('@name')[0] ; // name of the field
        $value = (string) $field ; // value of the field

        $scan[ $key ] = $value ; // add the field to the current scan info
    }

    $scans[] = $scan ; // add the current scan to the scan list
}

echo json_encode($scans);
```

Output :

```
[{
    "updated_on":"17 March, 2019, 03:10 ",
    "status":"In-transit",
    "reason_code_number":"002",
    "scan_status":"PICKUP",
    "location_city":"AMSTERDAM",
    "location_type":"Hub",
    "city_name":"AMSTERDAM",
    "Employee":"JOEL - O94383"
},{
    "updated_on":"18 March, 2019, 22:22 ",
    "status":"Bag scanned at Hub",
    "reason_code":" - ",
    "reason_code_number":"003",
    "scan_status":"IN",
    "location":"I1H",
    "location_city":"AMSTERDAM",
    "location_type":"Hub",
    "city_name":"AMSTERDAM",
    "Employee":"ELLEN - 49821"
}]
```

Comment: It worked pretty well, but how to call on specific elements based on their name.

Like I want only 3 values **updated_on,location_city, employee**

Comment: You can define an array `$neededKeys = array('updated_on', 'location_city', 'employee');` and add an extra test before adding the information to the `$scan` array : `if( in_array($key, $neededKeys) ) $scan[ $key ] = $value ;`